# Get value from pipeline with ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName

Tags: powershell, pipeline

I have some issues getting a value from the pipeline using `ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName`.

When I run `Get-Input -ComputerName 'PC-01' | Get-Data` the cmdlet `Get-Input` should simply return the computer name "PC-01", whereas the `Get-Data` function should return "Value passed from Get-Input: PC-01". Instead, I get this error:

```
Get-Data : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command
either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its
properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
At line:1 char:33
+ Get-Input -ComputerName PC-01 | Get-Data
+                                 ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (PC-01:PSObject) [Get-Data], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectNotBound,Get-Data
```

I have build these two small sample cmdlets just to get the hang of working with the pipeline.

```
function Get-Input {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory = $true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true
        )]
        [string]$ComputerName
    )

    Process {
        Write-Output -InputObject $ComputerName
    }
}

function Get-Data {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory = $true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true
        )]
        [string]$ComputerName
    )

    Process {
        Write-Output -InputObject "Value passed from Get-Input: $($ComputerName)."
    }
}
```

If I change `$ComputerName` to `$Name` and run the following, it works:

```
PS C:\Users\frede> Get-Service -Name AdobeARMservice | Get-Data
Value passed from Get-Input: AdobeARMservice.
```

If I have grasped the concept of the pipeline in PowerShell, I should be able to run the following command `Get-Input -ComputerName 'PC-01' | Get-Data` and have the ComputerName passed to `Get-Data`.

Is there something I need to declare somewhere?

Comment: I would urge you to do further debugging; you might find that piping objects returned from your functions to `Get-Member` will be educational.

Comment: Your `Get-Input` function doesn't do anything - it takes a string argument and outputs that same string - and the resulting string won't have a `ComputerName` property

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the name (`ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName`) indicates, you're telling the parser to bind a value based on a *property name*.

The `Get-Input` function will need to output an object that has a *property* named `ComputerName` for this to work:

```
function Get-Input
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory = $true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true
        )]
        [string]$ComputerName
    )

    process
    {
        Write-Output $(New-Object psobject -Propert @{ComputerName = $ComputerName})
    }
}
```

Now you can do:

```
Get-Input -ComputerName 'PC-01' |Get-Data
```

---

If you want `Get-Data` to support computer name input from `Get-Service`, you'll have to add an alias that matches the appropriate property name on the object types output by `Get-Service`, ie. `MachineName`:

```
function Get-Data
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory = $true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true
        )]
        [Alias('MachineName')]
        [string]$ComputerName
    )

    process
    {
        Write-Output -InputObject "Value passed from Get-Input: $($ComputerName)."
    }
}
```

And now both of these will work:

```
Get-Service -Name AdobeARMService |Get-Data
Get-Input -ComputerName PC-01 |Get-Data
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation and examples!

Answer (score -2):

you have to write also ValueFromPipeline=$true:

```
 Mandatory = $true,
 ValueFromPipeline=$true,
 ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true
```

Greetings
Jannik

Answer (score -2):

You will need this bud.

`ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName` is for boolean ($True / $False) and isn't looking for your string.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param
(
    [Parameter(
        Mandatory = $true,
        ValueFromPipeline = $true
    )]
    [string]$ComputerName
)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "`ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName` is for boolean"?

Comment: My apologies, not so much just boolean, but rather values. His `$ComputerName` would need to have a value, e.g. `$ComputerName.Name`.